# How do black firebombs differ from regular firebombs?

Tags: dark-souls

Black firebombs cost 500 souls whereas the regular ones cost 50. The black variety supposedly does "more damage" than the regular ones, but I can't find any information on how much damage either variety does and how/if they scale with level, stats, enemy type, etc.

Does the black version do ten times the damage? Are there any actual damage statistics available?

Comment: A Google search for "dark souls black firebomb" shows [this page](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/black-firebomb) as the top result, which states its damage number, how it compares to a regular firebomb, and that it does not scale with anything. Is there something extra you were looking for?

Comment: I did search. I found several wiki pages *similar* to the one posed by Chris, but not *that* page, and those pages did not specify the damage. I also found several other forums discussing this, and the consensus on those posts was that there was no damage information available. I also checked in-game descriptions. You should not assume that because you found information with a quick search, that no effort was made to search or that the poster is lazy. Slight variations in search queries produce dramatically different results, and Google is known to guess what you want and often gets it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Both  varieties of firebombs, black and regular, both inflict basic fire damage and do not scale with anything. The only difference is that black firebombs have a base damage of 250, which is 70 more damage than that of the normal firebomb at 180.